# Importing a distributed python package from Django view

Tags: django, macos, python-2.7

I am working on a Django project where I need to get search results from the Amazon Product Advertising API. I've successfully used the API in PHP but am now working on my first Django app. I have signed up for and have Amazon credentials, keys, secret keys, etc.

As a shortcut, I found and installed a distributed Python Package here:
https://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api/overview

**QUESTION 1**: Where and how do I access a non-Django-specific Python package within Django? Do I need to add a reference to the package in settings? The package example docs include an import statement, which seems to work in the Django shell (at least no error msg):

```
>>>from amazonproduct import API
>>>
```

**QUESTION 2**: When I want to send an installed Python package a search query from a Django view and template, how/where do I import the package's objects?

I have the Python package installed in the same local instance of Python as Django (running Python 2.7 and Django 1.5 on a Mac OS X 10.8.2).

I am obviously new to both Django and Python. I've been able to get Django models, views and templates working, and I have all of the front-end scripting written to parse and display XML results from the Amazon Product Advertising API. And the Python package seems to have all I need. But now I just need to figure out how to take advantage of the package's ability to create a signed request, call Amazon's RESTful service and parse the resulting XML.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're a little confused about python's packages and Django apps. As you know, Django is a web framework written in Python, thus, any python package/module/file could be imported inside your Django's code.

Django apps are also python packages, that's why you can do stuff like `from my_app import models` to import the models of `my_app`. The difference is that, generally, a Django app comes in with some *django specific* files (`models.py, views.py, urls.py`, etc ), hence you need to add them to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` in order to Django do the stuff that the app need to be done (generating the tables in it's `models.py` for example).

Regarding your question, that `amazonproduct` package it's indeed a Python package but not a Django app -it doesn't have any `views.py` nor `models.py`. It's just a python package which provides a friendly interface to query Amazon's data. That means you doesn't have to append it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`. What you want to do with it is import it **wherever** you need it in your code. I think is probably inside the `views.py` which is where you normally handle the logic of your application.

Resuming: Wherever you need to access methods or classes or functions from your `amazonproduct` package you just import it normally (as you described in your answer) and then instantiate the objects or call the methods you need normally. Passing the data you collect in the file you're working at.

Hope this gives some light. If you have any other doubt about Python's packages and modules please refer to this [doc session](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) that is **very** well documented.

Comment: Thanks @PauloBu for the pointer to the doc session on Python modules. I needed a more detailed overview of how Python worked outside of Django, and your explanation and link got me on the right track. I am going to work through it this week and will report back my final solution.